# Using populate in mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongoose, populate

I am new to mongoose and I tried to get the populate to work but the returned value is always null as if the reference would not exist in the collection, which is wrong :-)

Here is my code:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://192.168.1.119:27017/DIM').then(() => {
  let p = mongoose.model(
    'Profile',
    new mongoose.Schema({
      _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      Name: mongoose.Schema.Types.String,
    }),
    'Profile'
  )

  let m = mongoose.model(
    'User',
    new mongoose.Schema({
      _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      Email: mongoose.Schema.Types.String,
      ProfileId: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Profile',
      },
    }),
    'User'
  )

  try {
    m.find()
      .populate('ProfileId')
      .select('ProfileId Email _id')
      .exec()
      .then(ret => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(ret))
      })
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Error ' + err.message)
  }
})
```

And here is the return I get:

[{"_id":"5b3ca85a2fcf013a04594f79","Email":"sa","ProfileId":null},{"_id":"5b3ca85a2fcf013a04594f7d","Email":"remote_log","ProfileId":null}]

The profileId is always null.

Here is the content of the DB

[image: Database]

[image]

I must be doing something dumb but can't seem to find where.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[Null](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_(SQL)) by definition means "a data value that does not exist in the database". Is there anything stored in your collection to be read?

Comment: Yes, indeed, but there is something in the collection as you can see from the screenshots I added. So it should not be null according to me.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the issue was that the database I was connecting to was created by a c# app where the _id was not a Mongo ObjectId but a string GUID so my code had to be adapted to:

```
    let p = mongoose.model(
    'Profile',
    new mongoose.Schema({
      _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.String,
      Name: mongoose.Schema.Types.String,
    }),
    'Profile'
  )

  let m = mongoose.model(
    'User',
    new mongoose.Schema({
      _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.String,
      Email: mongoose.Schema.Types.String,
      ProfileId: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.String,
        ref: 'Profile',
      },
    }),
    'User'
  )
```